# Finding maximum area of a rectangle without MVT

Tags: calculus

Can questions like finding the maximum area of a rectangle with a given perimeter be answered within Euclidean(or Cartesian) framework? I mean without getting help from calculus and mean value theorem.

Comment: Please define "without getting help from calculus".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: use that $$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$$ for $a,b\geq 0$